Ubuntu 24.10 nautilus internal hard drive is missing
I'm upgrading to Ubuntu 24.10, then I saw the file manager. My internal hard drive is missing. Where is it?


This may be a bug, as the physical drive section does appear on my installation. If you can report the issue to Canonical, they may be able to find the cause and resolve it going forward. Be sure to include whether changes were made to the sidebar items before the upgrade process so the testers can better replicate the problem

Same for me, no internal on nautilus, I'm using the disks app to access the folder

Found a work around. Open the disks app, select the partition, click the gear > edit mount options > show in user interface.
